# Robust motion detection in C#

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv, motion-detection

Can anyone point me to a robust motion detection sample/implementation? I know EMGU has a motion detection sample, but its not very good, even small changes in light will be falsely detected as motion. I don't need to track objects. I am looking for a way to detect motion in a video that will not be falsely triggered by changing light conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/). Everything you should need is there (though you'll need to spend some time putting it all together), and it has a robust community if you need specific help.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with nizmahone. use Aforge:

Here is a link with soem motiond etection in C#:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Motion_Detection.aspx

Comment: I've seen this, this is simple background/foreground extraction.
If a cloud should pass you'll get crazy "motion" detected everywhere.